# Where does the Toast come from?

Tags: android, toast

Recently I need to modify one program as to add some new features. The program is used to collect the information around the mobile and send them to a server defined by the user or store the data on the SD card. But if we don't set the server host ourselves, the app will show a toast every 5 seconds when running:`localhost/127.0.0.1:5001 – Connection refused`.

Does anyone know how I can know this toast come from? Since there are some many places in the code we have a `toast.show()`.

Thanks in advance!
Here is the possible snippet of code which may cause the problem.

```
/**
     * Update GPS Status
     */
    public void updateGpsStatus(Context context, Handler handler) {
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            this.gpsStatus = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (handler == null) {
                ComFunc.showToast(context, e.getMessage());
            } else {
                ComFunc.showToast(context, e.getMessage(), handler);
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is probably coming from exception catch in one of your network connection methods (judging by the context).

Comment: Look in the log output for clues? `adb logcat`

Comment: Sorry crystal ball is broken. Show us the code and we can help.

Answer (score 1):

change all `toast.show` to `foo` and in `foo` check for the rogue string, if its there go to your breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to speculate since we have no idea what program you're talking about.

However, my first attempt would be to search my source code for `localhost/127.0.0.1:5001 – Connection refused` and find where that is being used.

The hostname/ip may be generated, so also try searching for `– Connection refused`

Comment: this is an exception message, it probably won't appear in the source.

Comment: MByD - Me too. I agree this is an exception message.